# Calculate Saturday following up to user form input date

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I have made a form where users can select a date from a calander. It wil return `d/m/Y`, 14/05/2013.

What i need is the Saturday following up that date 14/05/2013 what will be 18/05/2013

The date field is called: `$_POST['field_3']`

I have been struggling with `strtotime` but with no succes

I have done sofar:

```
<?php

$today = $_POST['field_3'];

$date = strtotime('d/m/Y','next Saturday', $today);

$initialString =  date('m/d/Y', $date);

$end = date('m/d/Y', strtotime( 'next saturday 11:59 pm', $date));

echo $today ."<br>";
echo $initialString . ' - ' . $end;

?>
```

which returns:

> 14/05/2013
>
> 01/01/1970 - 01/03/1970

Comment: Note that `strtotime` takes only 2 arguments at the most.

Answer (score 1):

Very basic, but this can help :

```
<?php

$year               = 2013; // use substr() (or other stuff) to set these variables
$month              = 5;
$day                = 14;

$newDate    = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $day, $year); // creates a date with previous variables

$dayOfWeek  = date('w', $newDate);                  // get the weekday number; 0 = sunday, ..., 6 = saturday

$numberOfDaysTillNextSaturday   = (6 == $dayOfWeek) ? 7 : (6 - $dayOfWeek); // how many days until next saturday ? If saturday = 6, otherwise = (Saturday - weekday)

$nextSaturdayDate   = $newDate + (86400 * $numberOfDaysTillNextSaturday);   // creates a new date corresponding to next saturday

$nextSaturdayString = date("d/m/Y", $nextSaturdayDate);                     // formats the new date as (day)/(month)/(year)

echo $nextSaturdayString;                                                   // echoes the string
?>
```

Comment: Thank's a lot Über, you pointed me to the right direction at this time of day. Here it is 10:50 AM.
I had to modify some to get the right input from the form, but your hint about subst() did help me a lot.
Now i made it:

$datum = $_POST['field_3'];
$year               = substr($datum,6) ; // use substr() (or other stuff) to set these variables
$month              = substr($datum,4,2);
$day                = substr($datum,0,2);

And it works as it should work.

Best 73's Frank